# Is there an accepted best practice in Java for deleting a list element while iterating over the list?

Tags: java, list, concurrentmodification

I'm finding conflicting advice over the best way to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` while doing this:

```
    List<Apple> Apples = appleCart.getApples();
    for (Apple apple : Apples)
    {
        delete(apple);
    }
```

I'm leaning towards using an `Iterator` in place of a `List` and calling its `remove` method.

Does that make the most sense here?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use an Iterator.  Then you could use its remove method.

```
  for (Iterator<Apple> appleIterator = Apples.iterator(); appleIterator.hasNext();) {
     Apple apple = appleIterator.next();
     if (apple.isTart()) {
        appleIterator.remove();
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a ConcurrentModificationException, you likely have multiple threads.

So the full answer includes both using Iterator.remove() *and* synchronizing access to the collection.

For example (where *lock* is synchronized on by all threads that may modify the list):

```
synchronized ( lock ) {
   List<Apple> apples = appleCart.getApples();
   for ( Iterator<Apple> it = apples.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
   {
      Apple a = it.next(); 
      if ( a.hasWorm() ) {
         it.remove();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The code he posted will always throw ConcurrentModification regardless of concurrency issues.  (Unless of course the list only has one element!)

Comment: In the OP's example, `ConcurrentModificationException` wouldn't involve multiple threads at all. It'd just be a result of removing from the list while iterating using its iterator.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Apple> apples = appleCart.getApples();
for (Iterator<Apple> appleIterator = apples.iterator(); appleIterator.hasNext();)
{
   Apple apple = appleIterator.next();
   if ( apple.isYucky() ) {
     appleIterator.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for thinking up the exact same code as me at the same time! :)

Comment: We have all been around this block.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of items to remove and then remove them after the loop:

```
List<Apple> apples = appleCart.getApples();
List<Apple> badApples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
for (Apple apple : apples) {
    if (apple.isBad()) {
        badApples.add(apple);
    } else {

    eat(apple);
}

apples.removeAll(badApples);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can now do this: 

`apples.removeIf(apple -> apple.equals(this))`